# OSM-Bright boundaries style

Tags: style, tile-server

Any reason why osm-bright style has the layers **boundary_2_z5_maritime** and **boundary_2_z0-4_maritime**, that have the exact same colors and style, such that that z5 is only taking over z0-4 from zoom 5 ?

I'm trying to build my own style and I'm confused to which added value z5 brings to the style, while it looks like we could only keep z0-4 and remove its maxzoom to cover the same need.

The only reason I would see is if there was another layer that could interact with the boundary layer and takes over its style but I can't see any (nor I can't see why you would overlap a boundary with another style, such as a string that would "cut" your boundary to get displayed).

```
   {
        "id": "boundary_2_z0-4_maritime",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "openmaptiles",
        "source-layer": "boundary",
        "minzoom": 0,
        "maxzoom": 5,
        "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round",
            "visibility": "visible"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "rgba(98,185,229,1)",
            "line-width": {
                "base": 1,
                "stops": [
                    [
                        3,
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        5,
                        1.2
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "line-opacity": 1
        },
        "metadata": {},
        "filter": [
            "all",
            [
                "==",
                "admin_level",
                2
            ],
            [
                "!has",
                "claimed_by"
            ],
            [
                "==",
                "disputed",
                0
            ],
            [
                "==",
                "maritime",
                1
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "boundary_2_z5_maritime",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "openmaptiles",
        "source-layer": "boundary",
        "minzoom": 5,
        "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round",
            "visibility": "visible"
        },
        "paint": {
            "line-color": "rgba(98,185,229,1)",
            "line-width": {
                "base": 1,
                "stops": [
                    [
                        5,
                        1.2
                    ],
                    [
                        12,
                        3
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "line-opacity": 1
        },
        "metadata": {},
        "filter": [
            "all",
            [
                "==",
                "admin_level",
                2
            ],
            [
                "==",
                "disputed",
                0
            ],
            [
                "==",
                "maritime",
                1
            ]
        ]
    }
```